# fileReadSync is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to use the readFileSync function but I keep getting the error "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): fs.readFileSync is not a function"

````
const fs = require('fs')

const readCSV = async (filePath) => {
    const csvFile = fs.readFile(filePath)
    const csvData = csvFile.toString()
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        Papa.parse(csvData, {
            header: true,
            complete: results => {
                console.log('Complete', results.data.length, 'records.');
                resolve(results.data);
            }
        });
    });
};

const test = async () => {
    let parsedData = await readCSV(csvFilePath);
}

test()```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vsth2.png
````

Comment: Where are you using the `readFileSync` function. In the above snippet you've used the `readFile.`

Comment: Sorry I forgot to edit it but I am having difficulty with using either the functions

Comment: This does not work `const csvFile = fs.readFile(filePath)`.  `fs.readFile()` is asynchronous and does not return the content.  You have to use a callback with it.  And, your title refers to `fileReadSync`, but that is not used anywhere in your code and isn't a built in function either.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this code may work?

```js
const fs = require('fs')

const readCSV = async (filePath) => {
    const csvFile = await fs.promises.readFile(filePath)
    const csvData = csvFile.toString()
    return await new Promise(resolve => {
        Papa.parse(csvData, {
            header: true,
            complete: results => {
                console.log('Complete', results.data.length, 'records.');
                resolve(results.data);
            }
        });
    });
};

const test = async () => {
    let parsedData = await readCSV(csvFilePath);
}
```

1. Changed readFile to promises.readFile, since you're doing it in an async function.
2. awaited your return promise so that you don't have to double await to get the result.

Comment: This seems to have gotten me further! However, I am now getting an error that says "Cannot read property 'readFile' of undefined".

Comment: Can you post a little more of the error? Perhaps its a dependency issue? What line number and file is this error originating from?

Comment: I've added the image to the post. It seems like this error only occurs when I actually call the function and try to log something

Comment: Well that would be why! You're trying to run node.js code on the client! FileSystem (aka, `fs`) doesn't exist there.

Comment: Is there anyway to still read the file without using File System. Thank you for the help!